# Laravel deep relation query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to get my models in deep relationships but it returns

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #5
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'gis-web.areas.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `zone_regions`.*, `areas`.*,
>   `segments`.* from `zone_regions` inner join `areas` on
>   `areas`.`zone_id` = `zone_regions`.`id` inner join `hthree_regions` on
>   `hthree_regions`.`area_id` = `areas`.`id` inner join `segments` on
>   `segments`.`hthree_id` = `hthree_regions`.`id` group by
>   `zone_regions`.`id`)

## Code

```
$data = DB::table('zone_regions')
        ->join('areas', 'areas.zone_id', '=', 'zone_regions.id')
        ->join('hthree_regions', 'hthree_regions.area_id', '=', 'areas.id')
        ->join('segments', 'segments.hthree_id', '=', 'hthree_regions.id')
        ->select(
            'zone_regions.*',
            'areas.*',
            'segments.*'
        )
        ->groupBy('zone_regions.id')
        ->get();
```

## Logic

1. `zone_regions` has `areas`
2. `areas` has `hthree_regions`
3. `hthree_regions` has `segments`
4. and so on later i will add...

#### what I want from this data?

I need to get `zone_regions` count of everything below it such as:

`zone_regions 1` has `20 areas`, `2000 hthree_regions` and `16000 segments`

So i can have count of all related rows to this `zone region` that's what I'm trying to achieve.

**Any idea?**

Comment: You are using `GROUP BY`, but are not selecting any count aggregates.  Did you intend to post some other Laravel query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no this is the code that i have please feel free to point me where i made mistake. thanks

Comment: mysql 5.75+ include `only_full_group_by` mode, it only allow you to select the fields in groupBy and the aggregates function.

Comment: another problem is you are selecting all fields from diff tables. Each these tables has same primary_key `id`, only one of `id` will works, the others will be covered.

Comment: @TsaiKoga thank you already solved the issue, will share my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

AS of struggling a lot with query approach I've decided to use model binding function `hasManyThrough` [source](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

I've defined 3 new functions in my model and called them in my variable (with) now i have my desired data.

## Code

`Model`

```
class ZoneRegion extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function areas(){
        return $this->hasMany(Area::class, 'zone_id', 'id');
    }

    public function segments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Segment::class, HthreeRegion::class, 'area_id', 'hthree_id');
    }

    public function links()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Link::class, Segment::class, 'hthree_id', 'segment_id');
    }

    public function cabels()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(CableType::class, Link::class, 'cable_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

`Controller`

```
$zones = ZoneRegion::orderby('id', 'desc')->with(['areas', 'segments', 'links', 'cabels'])->get();
```

And it does the trick, now all i need to do is to get `length` of my data (JS approach) or `count()` of my data (Blade approach)

Hope it can help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the "Strict Mode" is not turned off on your Laravel.

**Solution:**

1. Open  `yourproject/config/database.php`
2. Find `strict => true` (change it to false)

Don't forget to run `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: that fixes the error but the data in other hand are just returning from `segments` table nothing for `zone_regions` nor `hthree_regions`. it seems only getting latest `->join()`

Answer (score 0):

According with your error the problem is with your db, it say that you have enable

`sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

To disable this mode with

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

For more information you can review this documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Despite this, I can see that your query don't get that you want, You need aggregate function like count, some like.

```
data = DB::table('zone_regions') ->join('areas', 'areas.zone_id', '=', 'zone_regions.id') ->join('hthree_regions', 'hthree_regions.area_id', '=', 'areas.id') ->join('segments', 'segments.hthree_id', '=', 'hthree_regions.id') ->select( 'zone_regions.id' , DB::raw(' SUM(case when areas.id IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as areas,  SUM(case when hthree_regions.id.id IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as hthree_regions), SUM(case when segments.id IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as segments')->groupBy('zone_regions.id') ->get();
```

I hope help you